# Não obtendo resposta Socket IO

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io

Olá,

Podem me dizer por favor onde está o erro ?

Criei um arquivo na pasta raiz, `server.js`

```js
var socket  = require( 'socket.io' );
var express = require('express');
var app     = express();
var server  = require('http').createServer(app);
var io      = socket.listen( server );
var port    = process.env.PORT || 3000;

server.listen(port, function () {
    console.log('Server listening at port %d', port);
});


io.on('connection', function (socket) {
 socket.on( 'new_message', function( data ) {
  io.sockets.emit( 'new_message', {   
   id: data.id,
   titulo: data.titulo,
   mensagem: data.mensagem,
   created_at: data.created_at
  });
 });
});
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Agora em uma requisiçao ajax, faço a inclusão dos dados no banco e retorno em json.

O meu retorno no ajax, possui o seguinte código

```
if(data.success == true) {
    let socket = io.connect( 'http://'+window.location.hostname+':3000' );
    socket.emit('new_message', {
        id: data.id,
        titulo: data.titulo,
        mensagem: data.mensagem,
        created_at: data.created_at
    });
}
```

E estou tentando obter a resposta socket conforme abaixo, mas não estou tendo sucesso.

```js
let socket = io.connect( 'http://'+window.location.hostname+':3000' );
socket.on( 'new_message', function( data ) {
 console.log(data);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Problema resolvido, o retorno `json` estava como string, adicionei `header('Content-Type: application/json');` no retorno `PHP` e obtive sucesso.